# Set has_one relationship in form, but get object vs string exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, simple-form

I have a has_one relationship (organization has one template) in my model, and am trying to update it via a form. However, when I do so, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in OrganizationsController#update

Template(#70209323427700) expected, got String(#70209318932860)
```

This is slightly complicated by the fact that each organization has many templates associated with it, but only one current template, as shown in the model:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :subdomain, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :current_template, :presence => true


  has_many :organization_assignments
  has_many :people
  has_many :pages
  has_many :templates
  has_many :users, :through => :organization_assignments
  has_one :current_template, :class_name => 'Template'


  attr_accessible :name, :subdomain, :template_id, :current_template, :current_template_id
end
```

Here's my form:

```
= simple_form_for @organization, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  - @organization.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    .alert.alert-error
      %h3
        = pluralize(@organization.errors.count, 'error')
        prohibited this organization from being saved:
      %ul
        %li
          = msg

  = f.input :name

  = f.input :subdomain
  = f.input :current_template, :collection => @organization.templates, :selected => @organization.current_template

  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), organizations_path, :class => 'btn'
```

And just for good measure, my controller:

```
  def update
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @organization.update_attributes(params[:organization])
        format.html { redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I've tried using nested forms:

```
  = simple_fields_for :current_template do |f|
    = f.input :current_template, :collection => @organization.templates, :selected => @organization.current_template
```

But all that succeeds in doing is changing the ID #, without actually changing the associated form. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value of params[:organization][:template] is the string containing the ID of the selected template. You need to look up the actual instance of Template with that ID and assign to params[:organization][:template]. For example:

```
def update
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  if (params[:organization])
    params[:organization][:template] = Template.find(params[:organization].delete(:template))
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @organization.update_attributes(params[:organization])
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That works -- though can I ask why you put the delete method on the params?

Comment: Just habit. This is what I typically do in this kind of situation. Deleting the param is often useful when the user didn't select an item from a select widget - thus the param will be missing rather than the empty string. In this case, it's not an advantage since the empty string will cause the Template.find to fail.